# How do I populate the form fields with selected data?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a db which needs to add, edit, delete records.

The form adds successfully.

However, if I select a row from the displayed data, I want the form to populate, so the user can confirm either the edits they want to make, or this is the correct record to delete.

I have tried document.getElementbyID - but angular won't let me set the value.

I can get the values of the record. I just can't put them into the form fields.

component.html

```
      <span *ngFor="let top_page of top_page ; let i = index;"
      #nGForArray class="item-table">
        <div class="pageitem" (click)="fillform(top_page)">
          <div class="pagetitle col-3">{{top_page.title}}</div>
          <div class="pagedescription col-5">{{top_page.description}}</div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <form novalidate #formPage="ngForm"  class="col-12" > 
        <div class="col-5">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel id="formPageTitle" 
                  [value]="" name="title" #pageTitle="ngModel" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" ngModel name="formPageDescription"
                  id="description" [value]="" name="description" #pageDescription="ngModel" ></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
      <p>Title value: {{ pageTitle.value }}</p>
      <p>Form value: {{ formPage.value | json }}</p>
```

fillform()

```
fillform(single_page): void {
    this.isPageFormVisible = true;
    console.log(single_page);
    // none of the following work  
    // let tempTitle = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("formPageTitle")).value
    // tempTitle = single_page.title;
    // console.log(tempTitle);
    // this.formPage.value.pageTitle.value = single_page.title;
    // this.formPage.value.description.value  = single_page.description;
    // console.log(this.formPage.value.pageTitle.value);
    this.formPage.value.title.value = single_page.title.value;
    this.isCurrent = true;
  }
```

When a user clicks on a row (*ngFor of top_page) the fields from their selection should populate the form.

Comment: [(value)] <= you have to do this for Angular to have two-way data binding.

I'm not sure if this would work, please try it and tell me (fairly easy thing to do), it's called banana-in-a-box.

But the real solution from my POV should be using reactive forms instead of template-driven forms. Awaiting your results, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way binding of data to form will do what you are looking for.  Change your form part in html to following . I have only added two way binding using `[(ngModel)]`

```
 <form novalidate #formPage="ngForm"  class="col-12" > 
        <div class="col-5">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="title" id="formPageTitle" 
                  [value]="" name="title" #pageTitle="ngModel" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="description" name="formPageDescription"
                  id="description" [value]="" name="description" #pageDescription="ngModel" ></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Add following in your controller

```
title:String;
description:String;

fillform(single_page): void {
    this.isPageFormVisible = true;
    this.title=single_page.title;
this.description=single_page.description;
    this.isCurrent = true;
  }
```

Comment: I notice that in the input field  under Description you have the name attribute twice. 
Is this necessary. It one not correct?  IF so, which one can/should be removed?

Comment: it was already there:) check in your question , btw only one is required